# Syntax Error Trying To Run A Bundle Install GEMFILES

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gemfile

I'm following through a online course at https://onemonth.com/, I was asked to add the **bootstrap-sass** gem to my Gemfile and then run **bundle install**.

Below is my Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.1.1'

gem 'sqlite3'


gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'

gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'turbolinks'

gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'

gem 'bootstrap-sass',

gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

gem 'spring',        group: :development
```

I ran **bundle install** and a Error message appeared:

```
Gemfile syntax error on line 11: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting
keyword_do or '{' or '('
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
     ^
on line 11: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting end-of-input
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
```

I tried deleting the `','` after the `gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',` but nothing changed still giving me the same Error message...

Any idea of what's going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a comma at the end of the line. `gem 'bootstrap-sass',` should be `gem 'bootstrap-sass'`.

Answer (score 2):

```
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
```

change to :

```
group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0'
end
```